# VS2022 Interfering with VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build, hololens

I am trying to deploy a Unity project to the HoloLens. Unity succesfully builds the Visual Studio solution. This solution is to be built and deployed using VS2019. The solution builds without any errors using VS2019. However, when trying to build it in a machine that has both VS2019 and VS2022 installed, it fails because it tries to use VS2022's compiler and linker (even though I am executing the project in VS2019). If I uninstall VS2022, it works fine. It seems that it somehow tries to use the latest version installed as part of some of its configuration. This is part of the output when building the solution in VS2019.

[image]

As you can see in the image, it references 2022 instead of 2019. Is there a way I can change this? Or why is it using 2022 when installed?

Comment: It seems to be the default behavior of visual studio to select the latest MSVC. Do you encounter any issues when using Visual Studio 2022? In fact, VS 2022 is recommended version for MR development as it is stated on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools. In addition, if you try to build the project to HoloLens 2, you may need change the target platform to ARM64.

Comment: The project I am working won't build on VS2022. There are dependencies on it, and I use an older version of Unity. I did try VS2022 with older toolset intalled but no luck. As I mentioned in the post, there are no issues building with VS2019 when VS2022 is not installed in the machine.

Comment: This issue has been reported to the product team but it needs more time to dig into the root cause. According to the description, the current workaround is to uninstall the VS 2022 and please let me know if you have any business impact. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT, It is basically what I have been doing. Uninstall VS2022 when I have to deploy my VS2019 app. A little annoying, but I hope it gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio project is generated form the Unity il2cpp. It is possible that the Unity il2cpp build process hard codes the values for the Linker and Complier paths. However, the il2cpp build process is owned by Unity, there is no specific configuration that can let Visual Studio automatically choose the current Linker and Complier.

According to my experiences and the discussions in Unity forum,  Unity tries to use the latest compiler and link to take advantage of for ARM64. If there is no error, it is fine to use the latest msvc. If you have concerns, please find dedicated support from Unity community -- [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/index.html).